# Issue in clearing cache

Tags: views, caching

i have added modules to my website , but now when i want to open modules from admin section its showing blank and i am getting PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

[image]

Comment: Just disable then uninstall Views module and then enable it. See if that will make it work.

Comment: @AgA actually i don't even getting option to open module ,its giving blank white screen.

Comment: Then use Drush to uninstall

Answer (score 1):

Check in your database

1.If cache_views table is exist or not .if not exist  import this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cache_views` (
  `cid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.',
  `data` longblob COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.',
  `expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or 0 for never.',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry was created.',
  `serialized` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Generic cache table for caching things not separated out...';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run update.php?
May be your module need database updates.
Try www.yourdomain.com/update.php